# Unable to find ejabberd/src folder - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ejabberd

I am a newbie in Ubuntu and I am installing Ejabberd in Ubuntu. As of now everything seems ok and I am able to make it up and running. Now I need to install the patch from the link

http://www.ejabberd.im/aclpopulatesr

I was able to get the patch from the link
http://www.ejabberd.im/files/contributions/mod_shared_roster.erl.diff

But when I try to copy to Ejabberd folder, I am not able to find the src folder. I believe I am missing it or it is somewhere hidden. Could anyone help me in installing this patch in Ubuntu. That will be very helpful. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package does not contain sources. You need to download them separately if you want to compile your own version.

```
apt-get source ejabberd
apt-get install build-essential # make, compiler, system libraries, deb toolchain
apt-get build-dep ejabberd # any packages required to build this particular package
```

Now patch, build, install.

This is obviously just a quick whirlwind intro. You probably want to google a few examples to get a fuller picture. There are [several for `ejabberd`](https://www.google.com/search?q=apt-get+build-dep+ejabberd) alone.

In particular, you need to understand how to give your local package a [version number which is higher](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage#Versioning) than the current official package, but lower than any future official upgrade.

Alternatively, find someone who has already done this and published the resulting package in a PPA. (Obviously, trust them to not trojanize the binary, or don't install it.)

Comment: I'd note that for just *building* external modules (not patching the `ejabberd`'s own code), no source is required as `ejabberd` is shipped with the relevant header files (`.hrl).